# How to increase the payload for the KUKA arm with KR210 claw?

Tags: motion-planning, path-planning, kuka

https://github.com/udacity/RoboND-Kinematics-Project

We are using the above mentioned KUKA arm model to simulate pick and place. We noticed that KUKA arm would not pick objects heavier than 2.5 kg in simulation. We are not sure if this is a simulation limitation or limitation of the gripper (KR210 claw).

Where can we find the specifications of KR210 claw? If we can get KUKA arm to carry heavier payload in simulation, where do we do that parameter tweaking?

Are there any other KUKA arm compatible grippers with DAE/STL files available, which has a higher payload capability?

Does the weight of the object to be picked, influence the trajectory/path planning by OMPL?

Comment: Actually, it is probably a limitation of the motors used in the arm, rather than the gripper. Take a look at the _Force Calculations of Joints_ section in this [simple tutorial](http://www.societyofrobots.com/robot_arm_tutorial.shtml)

Comment: Thanks sempaiscuba. Actually, the KUKA arm KR210 is capable of lifting upto 150Kg, so not sure why it is struggling here. See the specifications (https://www.kuka.com/-/media/kuka-downloads/imported/48ec812b1b2947898ac2598aff70abc0/spez_kr_2102_f_exclusive_en.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

You shoudl separate 2 things, the robotic arm and the gripper mounted on it, typically they come from different manufacturer. Both have physical limits that you need to take care when operating them.

From KUKA documentation about the KR210 serie (https://www.kuka.com/-/media/kuka-downloads/.../pf0031_kr_2102_k_en.pdf ) it seems that you should look a the limitation of the gripper. However note that even if the robotic arm can bear your payload, it might that not all configuration/motion are possible without violating the joint limits.

I went through the package quickly I found no information about the gripper model used.

If you want to simulate a specific KUKA arm, there are usually several projects available on the internet for each arm, so you can try out the one corresponding to your arm. Some have already some gripper model and some let you easily add your desired gripper. I suggest you to have a look at ROS industrial to find simulation of robotic arms and grippers used in the industry.

Lastly, the weight of the object as an influence as OMPL should check the robotic arm joint limits.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85784/discussion-on-answer-by-n-staub-how-to-increase-the-payload-for-the-kuka-arm-wi).

Comment: Generally speaking, it is better to edit your answer to add information requested in comments, rather than adding more comments. Comments are for helping to improve questions and answers, and are distracting, so we try to keep them to a minimum. If all of the information needed to answer the question is contained within it, the comments can be tidied up (deleted).